# How do I teleport a horse with through tags (like is tamed or is saddled) in Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my older brother have a multiplayer Minecraft world, he was out adventuring and died, leaving his max stats horse behind and we can't find it. So I decided to try to /tp it to me through it's tag as the horse is tamed and has a saddle, there's only 2 of those in our world one being mine and the other being his... though I can't seem to find how, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Regardless of the command, this wouldn’t work unless you were nearby the last known location because otherwise the chunks wouldn’t be loaded

Comment: yes yes, i know, my brother has the reference of z -50 so i've been trying there using his description to find the place

Comment: What I am thinking right now is --- if you have access to commands, why won't you summon a completely same horse with a custom name, armor set, HP, and all type of stats?

Comment: it's because it wouldn't be that horse anymore, that's just the same as picking another one up, we want that specific one back, you can even take atatchement as a reason if you may... And also because we only put commands up because i thought i could get him back through /tp like in Java version, using the [tag] thing

Comment: In bedrock there aren't NBT tags.